# Selective inheritance C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

Could you please explain why following code does compile and works fine (checked on gcc-4.3.4). I thought selective inheritance cannot weaken or even strengthen access to members/methods. Doesn't it break encapsulation rules?

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
protected:
    void foo() { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;  }
};

class B : private A {
public:
    using A::foo;   //foo() becomes public?!
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me something.

Comment: You do this when inheriting privately from standard containers. Basically, you forbid upcasting (this implies that you don't need a virtual destructor), but you allow some operations which would be tedious to reimplement / forward.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the language point of view, there's nothing wrong with this (whether it's good design is another matter).

Any class can choose to expose to a wider audience things that it has access to.

In principle, your example is no different to:

```
class B : private A {
public:
    void bar() { foo(); }
};
```

except that here `foo()` is exposed by proxy.

What you can't do is the opposite: a publicly derived class can't restrict access to things that are accessible via the base class.

Comment: Sure you can; in `struct A { int i; }; struct B: A { private: using A::i; };` the name `B::i` aliases and shadows `A::i` with private access.  Of course, that doesn't stop you writing `b.A::i`, which is perhaps what you meant.

Comment: @ecatmur: `B` can obfuscate things, but it can't restrict access. I can always upcast the reference to `A&` and use `A`'s API: `A& a = b; a.i = 42;`

Comment: @ecatmur: My choice of the word *hide* was a bit unfortunate. I've improved the wording.

Comment: @NPE: Access is checked statically, in the same way that you can upcast to gain access in ecatmur's example, you can upcast to loose access privilege. This has nothing to do with obfuscation, but with the base principles on which the language is constructed.

Comment: *whether it's good design is another matter* => it can be useful to add, for example, a method to `std::vector`, while I generally advise free-functions for this some people are reluctant (living and dying by objects...) and in this case `private` inheritance + method forwarding allows to emulate mixins.